# How to extract data from a field that is apparently of the date / time format but is not really such a format

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have copied (copy/paste) a part of a home-page into an empty excel. One of the fields looks like this: 3140:01:00. If I check the format, it shows that the category is custom, and that the type is [t]:mm:ss. The problem is that I am only interested in the first 4 digits shown plus digits 6 and 7. If I change the format to e.g. text, I end up with a number. Probably a number, that identifies a specific date. In fact the first 4 digits are the length of a horse race! :-) I'm new at VB, but I have managed to clean up the rest of the information - but not this. Probably a known problem. Please help!

Comment: Can't you just parse the digits into two new fields formatted as numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to understand the difference between the value and the representation of your data (note that this is not VBA but Excel related). When you enter `3140:01:00` in a cell in Excel, Excel tries to understand what you enter. With the colon, it looks somehow like a time value, so Excel guesses that this a a time, convert what you enter into a date value (a date in Excel has automatically a time part) and put a number format that displays this date+time as `[h]:mm:ss`.

As I said, internally, what you entered is converted into a Date. Now a Date in Excel in internally stored as a number. If you set the number format to "Number", the cell will display `130.83402`. This is because 3140 hours = 130 days + 20 hours. The 20 hours (plus the 1 minute) are stored as a fraction of a day (0.83402).

If you format the same value as Date/Time, you will see (depending on your regional settings) something like `05/09/1900  20:01:00` - because that is the 130th day in the Excel calendar (day 1 in Excel is 1/1/1900). Note that the *value* of the cell doesn't change, only the way it is displayed.

If you could prevent Excel to convert your input into a date, the solution would be to do string-handling, eg use the `Split`-function. When you format a cell as `Text` and enter `3140:01:00` manually, Excel leaves the string untouched and this would work. However, it seems that when you *Paste* the value into the cell, the number format is set automatically and the value is converted into a date even if the cell was formatted as Text before. I don't know if there is a way to tell Excel to *not* convert the data if it is pasted.

So what we can do instead is to convert the date value back into "hours", "minutes" and "seconds" - even if the "hours" are in fact something else (meters? yards? horse length?), and the minutes are probably also not minutes but whatever.

Several ways to do so.
If you don't mind that the strange pseudo-date value remains in your Excel (you can hide the column with that value), use just 2 simple formulas. Assuming your "date" is in D2:

- use the formula `=TRUNC(24*D2)` to get the horse race length (the first number). We cannot use the `Hour`-formula here as this would return only 20 and not 3140.
- use the formula `=MINUTE(D2)` to get the second number
- use the formula `=SECOND(D2)` to get the third number

If you want to involve VBA:

```
Sub SplitStrangeDate(cell As Range)
    If Not IsDate(cell) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim d As Date
    d = cell.Value
    
    Dim v1 As Long, v2 As Long, v3 As Long
    v1 = CLng(d * 24)
    v2 = Minute(d)
    v3 = Second(d)
    Debug.Print v1, v2, v3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I could not get =trunc etc. to work, but never mind. I copied your VBA code into my existing modules and it works perfectly. Thank you again for very good advice.